# PHP Facebook SDK how to GET graph API without token

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm able to get id & from->id when I simply CURL this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=729809777049118&set=a.477834652246633.125010.477814995581932&type=1
```

However i receive OAuthException when i use the same URL with PHP SDK -

```
$result = $facebook->api('https://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . urlencode('https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=729809777049118&set=a.477834652246633.125010.477814995581932&type=1'),'GET');
```

Is there anyway I can make it work with SDK the same way it works simply using CURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use it with PHP SDK you should remove the first part of the url:

```
$result = $facebook->api(urlencode('https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=729809777049118&set=a.477834652246633.125010.477814995581932&type=1'),'GET');
```